# .net hang on Application.DoEvents

Tags: .net, freeze, doevents

One of our legacy products is a Winforms application and instead of using background threads it does everything on the main UI thread. It has a constant loop running on this main thread that calls Application.DoEvents() every 20 ms. Once in a while the application just hangs at the DoEvents call. My question is how do I find out in what queued event call the code is hanging?

P.S. Does someone know of a tool that I can use to get the stack trace of every thread in a process?

Also, this is only happening at a production client and we got to get a fix out now. No possibility in installing VS at the client either.

Comment: That code needs to *seriously* be refactored.

Comment: Does it hang during debugging?

Comment: Tool is called Visual Studio. You pause process, and go to Threads window.

Comment: If everything is done on the UI thread you only need to get the stack trace of the UI thread.

Comment: I second @Tejs, the time for analyzing the problem is better spend in refactoring your form. Basically you have to move the loop to a background worker thread and change any call from the background thread into the UI thread so that it is using the BeginInvoke-pattern.

Comment: Looks like we are going to refactor the code... when I posted I didn't think it was an option because my dev said it would be significant work but when looked at closer it isn't that bad at least just for that one form.

Comment: BTW Tejs, although you didn't really answer my question the solution  to the hang issue is to refactor. Post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the tool I was looking for. [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)

It can get the stack traces for a currently running windows process. However it does require the PDB files for that application.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in visual studio, just attach to the process, break execution and open the threads windows.

Menu: Debug->Windows->Threads

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work. The issue is being experienced at a customer and we can't reproduce it in-house or install VS on their machine. I will edit the original question.